# Плавный scroll с помощью window.scrollBy()

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать плавный scroll c помощью `window.scrollBy()`.

```js
const btnPort = document.getElementById('port');


btnPort.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  window.scrollBy(0, 800);
});
```

```css
.final {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="promo">
      <div class="promo__btns">
        <a class="promo__link  btn" href="#" id="port">НАЖМИ</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  
  <div class="final">
      <h1 class="final__block">ФИНАЛ<h1>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `scrollBy` можно передать `options` объект, в котором параметр `behavior` отвечает за поведение прокрутки.

```js
const btnPort = document.getElementById('port');


btnPort.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  window.scrollBy({
    top: 800,
    behavior : "smooth"
  });
});
```

```css
.final {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo">
      <div class="promo__btns">
        <a class="promo__link  btn" href="#" id="port">НАЖМИ</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  
  <div class="final">
      <h1 class="final__block">ФИНАЛ<h1>
  <div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !!!

Comment: @ИгорьБабиков, Не за что) а так же прошу поставить галочку на против моего ответа.